# Get results from a for loop in Python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, pywhois

I am new to coding in Python and ran into an issue.
I have a list of domain names that I would like to get whois lookup information of.
I am using a for look to get whois information on every domain in the list called domain_name like this:

```
for i in domain_name:
    print(whois.whois(i))
```

I am getting the results printed just fine. But I would like to save those results in a variable that I can make a list of dataframe out of.
How do I go about doing that?

thank you!

Comment: `data = [whois.whois(name) for name in domain_names]`

Answer (score 2):

A [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) is appropriate here, useful if you are starting with one list and want to create a new one.

```
my_results = [whois.whois(i) for i in domain_name]
```

Will create a new list with the whois results.

Comment: amazing! this really works. Thank you for the reference also

Answer (score 0):

Define the list you want to store them in before the loop then append them to it inside the loop:

```py
my_container = []
for domain in domain_names:
   my_container.append(whois.whois(domain))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I really appreciate you prompt response. Your answer did exactly what I wanted.  Here's the code:
my_container = []
for domain in domain_names:
   my_container.append(whois.whois(domain))

I got all the results for every domain name in my list saved into my_container list.